# What's the meaning of the code snippet about objective-c

Tags: objective-c

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool=[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
```

I want to know the meaning of this sentence and how to use it.

My programming environment is established by GNU Gcc under win7.

Comment: I'm not an expert on Objective-C but here is a great start to learn about the [NSAutoreleasePool](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAutoreleasePool_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: You should probably start by reading a decent book on Objective C - you can't learn a new programming language by guesswork and asking random questions on SO.

Comment: While we generally accept even beginner-level questions here, this could have been found in five minutes by searching any Objective-C documentation, like the one linked by Minion91. With all due respect, I'd highly recommend reading a good introductory guide to Objective-C, like this one: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH1-SW2 before proceeding further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It creates and initializes an NSAutoreleasePool object.  [NSAutoreleasePool alloc] allocates the memory for it and clears it to zero; calling init on that invokes its init method, which generally does whatever a class needs to do upon startup.  The little "=" sign indicates assignment, storing the object just created and initialized into a local variable called "pool" which is an NSAutoreleasePool pointer.

This line generally occurs in the main program of iOS apps, creating a default autorelease pool for the whole app.  But it is sometimes used elsewhere, to create a temporary pool for some specific purpose.  Googling NSAutoreleasePool will surely lead you to its documentation.